# Firebase authentication sign in problem in java

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I wrote a login system using Firebase. What I want to do now :

If the user has trouble registering (for example, if he tries to log in with an already registered e-mail), I want to print the error in the warning message and redirect it to the sign-up page.

For this, I have written a code such as below, into register button.

```
   // Sign Up Method
    // Kullanıcı Kayıt etme metodu
   public void signUp(View view) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailText.getText().toString(),passwordText.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(signupPage.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent homePage = new Intent(signupPage.this, ProfilePage.class);
                        startActivity(homePage);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    Intent signBack = new Intent(signupPage.this, signupPage.class);
                    startActivity(signBack);
                    finish();
                }
                Toast.makeText(signupPage.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If there is a problem when User logging in, doing show error message. But it does not redirect to the registration page. Although it shows an error, the user redirects it to the home page as if it were registered successfully.

I would appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you must to know that the onComplete method will be called always, since onFailure only when something fails. So, as I see on your code the app will always launch home.

How to solve?
Just check if the task is successful for redirect to homepage.

In the onComplete method check if all is ok and execute your code with: if (task.isSuccessful)...

Comment: Thank you so much! I was built the wrong logic. When you do as you said, it improved.

I thought FailureListener like else in if else.

Comment: If you want to do like if else, you can use both onSuccessListener and onFailureListener, they will be called only when it success or fails.

Comment: I will try. Thank you very much, Davis.